# The one to one map between two representations

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There is a quotation below (C*-Algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations):

$ \qquad$For a discrete group $\Gamma$ we let $\lambda:\Gamma\rightarrow B(l^{2}(\Gamma))$ denote the **left regular representation**: $\lambda_{s}(\delta_{t})=\delta_{st}~$ for all $s, t\in \Gamma$, where $\{\delta_{t}: t\in \Gamma\}\subset l^{2}(\Gamma)$ is the canonical orthonormal basis.

$ \qquad$We denote the **group ring** of $\Gamma$ by $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$. By definition, it is the set of formal sums 
$$\sum_{s\in \Gamma}a_{s}s,$$
where only finitely many of the scalar coefficients $a_{s}\in \mathbb{C}$ are nonzero, and multiplication is defined by

$$\Big(\sum_{s\in \Gamma}a_{s}s\Big)\Big(\sum_{t\in \Gamma}a_{t}t\Big)=\sum_{s, t\in \Gamma}a_{s}a_{t}st.$$
The group ring $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$ acquires an involution by declaring $\displaystyle\Big(\sum_{s\in \Gamma}a_{s}s\Big)^*=\sum{s\in \Gamma}\bar{a_{s}}s^{-1}$. Note that the left regular representation can be extended to an injective *-homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]\rightarrow \mathbb{B}(l^{2}(\Gamma))$, which we also denote by $\lambda$. **Evidently, there is a one-to-one correspondence between unitary representations of $\Gamma$ and *-representations of $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$.**

**My question is : Could someone explain the "Evidently" above to me ? Thanks.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H$ is a Hilbert space, given a unitary representation $\gamma:\Gamma\rightarrow\mathcal{U}(H)$, how do you induce a (at first, simply linear) function $\widetilde{\gamma}:\mathbb{C}(\Gamma)\rightarrow\mathcal{B}(H)$? What about the converse: if $c:\mathbb{C}(\Gamma)\rightarrow\mathcal{B}(H)$ is a (unital) *-representation, how do you obtain a unitary representation $\overline{c}:\Gamma\rightarrow\mathcal{U}(H)$? (*Hint: For $s\in \Gamma$, we have $s=1s\in\mathbb{C}(\Gamma)$*)

**Answer:**

> $$\widetilde{\gamma}(\sum a_s s)=\sum a_s\gamma(s)\quad\text{and}\quad\overline{c}(s)=c(1s).$$

Comment: But what is your $\delta_{s}$ means here? I think $\delta_{s}$ should be contained in $\mathbb{B}(l^{2}(\Gamma))$.

Comment: @Belle-tiantian Oh. I'm sorry about that. I'm missed some notation there. Edited it.

Comment: I am sorry, I still do not know what does $1_{s}(\in C(Γ))$ means, here. And why does it have relationship with $s\in \Gamma$?

Comment: First, in the notation used, $1_s$ does not make sense, but $1s$ does: it is simply an element of $\mathbb{C}(\Gamma)$ as you defined, since it is a formal sum consisting of only one term (I believe you mean $\mathbb{C}(\Gamma)$ instead of $C(\Gamma)$ in your comment). Obviously. the mapping $s\in\Gamma\mapsto 1s\in\mathbb{C}(\Gamma)$ is injective, so that is the relation you wanted.